# Calculate $2^n \pmod{14^8}$ with large numbers quickly

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, hyperoperation

Is there a way to calculate $2^n \pmod{14^8}$ faster than binary exponentiation? The $n$ values in question are very large, for example $2^{65536}$, and the calculations have to be done around $14^8$ times. The ultimate goal is to calculate numbers that use Knuth's up-arrow notation. Maybe the Chinese Remainder Theorem can be used here to reduce the problem space from $14^8$ to $7^8$ or further, as I am using arrays to memoize values.

Comment: You could at least use the chinese remainder theorem to reduce it to a $\mod 7^8$ problem.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Any method to reduce the modulus, especially on the order of $10^6$, will be very useful in computation

Comment: http://guan.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/note/expn.pdf
There are several algorithms listed here. Most of them are modified versions of the binary method, but they might help some. As was pointed out by @zibadawatimmy you could reduce the numbers somewhat based on  their factors.

Comment: Binary exponentiation would only require 16 steps; that's not too much...

Comment: @MihirSinghal I don't think that is correct. I am dealing with $ 2^{2^{65536}} $ here.

Comment: Roughly on what time frame do the ~$14^{8}$ calculations need to be completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256657/exponentiation-and-modular-arithmetic). In summary, divide $14^8$ by $2^8$, and use Euler's theorem to find the exponent  $\mod \varphi(7^8)$.